# create enum with MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I would like to create an enum to store all strings and then access to then from other files
the objective is to centralize all strings in one function

is there a way to create an enum with MATLAB ?

Thanks

Comment: A cell array of strings might achieve what you want. Can you give an example of how you want to use this 'enum'?

Comment: Otherwise http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/enumerations.html as the accepted answer in that previous question is out of date